# Tmux: Binding a key to multiple commands and saving output in environment variable to (un)hide a pane

Tags: tmux

I have been researching how to hide and unhide panes in tmux. I want to bind a key to quickly do this. With `break-pane` I can hide a pane, and the output of the command is the name of the pane (:window.pane if I get it right). So I want to bind a key that executes `break-pane` stores the output in an environment variable and then later on, to un-hide it, take the environment variable and uses it to `join-pane` that pane again.
This is where I am so far:

```
bind h run-shell "export HIDDEN_PANE=$(tmux break-pane -dP)"
bind H join-pane -vs $HIDDEN_PANE
```

Right now, the hiding works, but how do I take the output of break-pane, and store it in the `HIDDEN_PANE` environment variable as part of the same bind command, so I can then use it later in the join-pane command in a different pane (and therefore shell)? Right now the environment variable doesn't get set anywhere as evidenced by <kbd>Prefix</kbd>+<kbd>:</kbd>+`show-environment`

Answer (score 3):

After a low of trial and error, googling and and man-page reading, this is what I ended up doing.

Additionally to my question, I had the following requirement:

I need to be able to hide multiple panes and distinguish between them when unhiding. This means that if I hide a pane, tmux needs to store the relevant information for the hidden pane in a way, that when I unhide a pane, it knows to restore the pane that was originally below the "current" pane.

That being said, this is my solution in `~/.tmux.conf`:

```
bind h run-shell "tmux setw $(echo @HIDDEN_PANE_#{pane_id}|sed -e 's/%//g') $(tmux break-pane -dP)"
bind H run-shell "tmux join-pane -hs $(tmux showw -v @HIDDEN_PANE_$(tmux run-shell \"echo '#{pane_id}+1'|sed -e 's/%//g'|bc\"))"
```

EDIT: Thanks to @NicholasMariott for the comment about user options (I was using environment variables before).

With <kbd>Prefix</kbd>-<kbd>:</kbd>-<kbd>h</kbd> I can hide a pane. It stores the relevant info from break-pane (which hides the pane) in a window user option (options starting with @ are user options), so the variable is window specific. To distinguish between the panes, the user option makes use of the tmux variable `#{pane_id}` which starts with a `%` followed by the numeric ID of the pane. To not run into issues, the `%` character is removed from the id. So the pane information from break-pane is stored in an option like `@HIDDEN_PANE_2` if pane `%2` was hidden.

To restore the pane with <kbd>Prefix</kbd>-<kbd>:</kbd>-<kbd>H</kbd> I use `tmux showw -v` to show the option. But in this case, it constructs the variable name for the "current" `#{pane_id}`+1, which should be the id of the pane "below" the current one, so that is the one to restore. `bc` is used to do the actual addition.

This seems to work for me, even though it is quite a monstrosity :) Any comments are welcome and I'll try to include them in the answer.

Possible improvements are to put it in a separate bash script that I run from tmux.conf with run-shell. In there I could then also test for vertically vs horizontally split panes, (using `#{window_height} - #{pane_height}`) and adjust the join-pane accoringly (`join-pane -vs` versus `join-pane -hs`).

Also the variable names could be adjusted to be more robust like by including the window/session ids.

Comment: You could use user options instead of environment variables which would avoid polluting the environment of all new panes - and "show -v" will return only the value so you could leave out the sed.

Comment: thanks @NicholasMarriott I didn't know that. It's still WIP so will modify